# Airflow: How to run same query on multiple databases

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, airflow

I need to execute a SQL query on multiple databases (10K) with the same schema and insert the results into a separate host using airflow.

Do you have any idea how I should design my DAG in the most efficient way for this kind of project?

Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One connection per database in Airflow.
Then define a list of those connection id strings.
Then repeat a task definition for the same task on each of the connection strings.

E.G. With MysqlOperator (see also MssqlOperator or PostgresOperator)

```
conns = ('db1','db2','db3')
tasks = [MysqlOperator("""
show tables;
""",
                       task_id="update_" + conn,
                       mysql_conn_id=conn,
          ) for conn in conns]
```

Comment: @Codutie It would be inside a `with DAG(...) as dag:` block and if you have dependencies you probably want to add a downstream or upstream task to each generated task.

Comment: I am not sure about the original poster, but this only works if the list of connections is known at parse time, and if the connections would be generated by another task upstream this wouldn't do (see eg. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56556790/5122790)